# Calling error message even though there is none

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to check if an email exists in the system, before a user is created. I'm using PHP and jQuery (AJAX, plugin).

Even though there is none in the database with the same email, my script writes that there is an existing identical e-mail. But it still creates the user (which it should).

If there *is* an existing e-mail, it's not creating the user, and it's writing the correct error message.

I don't know if it's my AJAX that's wrong?

My PHP:

```
$check_email = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE email='$email'");
$email_count = mysql_num_rows($check_email);

if($email_count>0){
echo "Email exists";
    return false;
}
```

And my jQuery:

```
$(function() {  
    $("#goNewUser").click(function() {  
        // validate and process form here  

        var username = $("input#username").val();  
        if(username == "") {
            $("input#username").focus();  
        return false;
        }

        var email = $("input#email").val();  
        if(email == "") {  
            $("input#email").focus();  
        return false;
        }

        var password = $("input#password").val();  
        if(password == "") {  
            $("input#password").focus();  
        return false;
        } 

        var salt = $("input#salt").val();
        if(salt == ""){
            $("input#username").focus();
        return false;
        }

        var dataString = 'username=' + username + '&email=' + email + '&password=' + password + '&salt=' + salt;  
        //alert (dataString);
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "includes/classes/handler.php?do=addLogin",
            data: dataString,  
            success: function(returnedData){

                if(returnedData == ''){
                    $('.sideBarNewUserWrap').fadeOut();
                } else {
                    $('.errorMessage').fadeIn().html(returnedData);
                }

            }
        });  
        return false;
  });  
});
```

Comment: have you checked if $email contains the right email provided by the user?

Comment: its advisable to use a separate php file for handling that error. use includes/classes/handle_error.php instead of includes/classes/handler.php?do=addLogin

Comment: Im not using handler.php for the errors. It's programmed OOP. And handler is just a middle man for the class file.

Comment: Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$email` before putting it into your SQL statement to assist in preventing SQL injection. In your JS send across the data as a JS object rather than putting it into an unescaped query string.

Comment: You should use a form for the ajax post. Use `$('form').serialize()` to get all the needed params. Also use a jQuery validation plugin with the form instead of checking the fields one by one.

Comment: @Treffynnon I got the SQL injection prevents. And how do I send it as a JS object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You'd better use PDO ;) It does all the protection needed if you use
   it right. Because now you have a lot of security holes - you do no
   query escaping, you are checking for field value equality (while it
   is better to use regular expression or at least truncate the value
   from possible spaces)
2. Your check is a bit rough. Try to use `SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM
   table WHERE email = '$email';` and check if
   `intval($first_row_of_result['cnt']) > 0`.
3. How do you perform a user creation process? If your code is previous
   to the user creation one and both they are parts of one function -
   yeah, you are right. You are right if you perform `if
   (!email_exists($email)) return false;` before creating a user.
   Otherwise i can not tell for sure if that process is correct.

Oh, yeah...

```
var dataString = 'username=' + username + '&email=' + email + '&password=' + password + '&salt=' + salt;  

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "includes/classes/handler.php?do=addLogin",
    data: dataString,  
    success: function(returnedData){ }
});
```

It is surely better do not use manual data escaping - try passing JSON object instead of `dataString`. jQuery will handle it for sure.

And you'd better use `FireBug` or other tool to replace any `alert(something)` with `console.log(something)` - it is more pretty ;)

And one more: you'd better use negate condition:

```
if (returnedData){
  $('.errorMessage').fadeIn().html(returnedData);
} else {
  $('.sideBarNewUserWrap').fadeOut();
}
```

Hope any of that would help you.

Comment: In particular, `$('form').submit(function(){var dataString = $(this).serialize(); $.ajax(...););` would probably help.

Comment: yeah, it is even better =) gotta take a note on that =)

Comment: Thanks man. I just need to know something: PDO, is that instead of mysql_real_escape_string etc. etc.? And the JSON object - is that more safe, or what do you mean by: jQuery will handle it for sure?

Comment: @Kolind PDO is the more flexible way to handle DB routines: queries, escapes, etc. SO, yeah, you're right =) And the JSON object is more flexible too - you can perform some transformations etc. That is as secure/safe as serialization (the first comment under this answer) =)

Comment: @shybovycha I will be looking at PDO. About the serialize. How do I handle the data in my PHP then? Could we maybe start a chat you and I? Wouldn't it be smarter?

Comment: @Kolind sure. Would you like stackoverflow's chat or GTalk/email one? =) And the data you will be receiving over POST - nothing changes at this point.

Comment: @Let's do it at Stackoverflow.. Uhm, the chat room is : shybovycha